# Get value for Count(*) with OracleDataReader

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I'm stuck reading the number of rows from a oracle table. As you can see on the picture I get the correct value (2.007.191) but cannot safe it in an `Int64`.

[image]

I already tried `Int64 count2 = (Int64) command.ExecuteScalar();` and `Int64 test2 = reader.GetInt64(0);` and also both with `Int32`but always get the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetInt64(Int32 i)

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Can you please show relevant code as a text?

Comment: what is actual type? `command.ExecuteScalar().GetType()`; looks that you have to do `(int) command.ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data reader requires you to `Read` first, before you actually are trying to get a value.

So you should start with:

```
long test2;
if (reader.Read())
{
    // read the first and only line
    test2 = reader.GetInt64(0);
}
else
{
    test2 = 0;
}
```

Usually with a data reader, you would expect multiple rows, you would use a `while` insteaf of an `if`.

And for your `ExecuteScalar` call, you might need `Convert.ToInt64`:

```
long count2 = Convert.ToInt64(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: `long count2 = Convert.ToInt64(command.ExecuteScalar());` works but `test2 = reader.GetInt64(0);` gives me the error `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetInt64(Int32 i)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should check reader has value before reading it:

```
if(reader.Read())
{
    long test2 = Convert.ToInt64(reader[0]);
}
```

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yup you are right only one value will be there..thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I found useful was `var test = reader.GetValue(0);`
then you can discover the type of test.